# How to enable animation for Eevee at this early stage on Mac

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I heard that Modifier is supported on Eevee via --enable-copy-on-write but then when running on Mac, I am not sure how to execute this on the command line? Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figure it out myself, on the Terminal:

```
cd /Applications/Blender
./blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender --enable-copy-on-write
```

```
cd /Users/username/Downloads/blender-2.80.0-git20180507.e3d30ffb920-x86_64
./blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender --enable-copy-on-write
```